# maven package: skip successfully built sub-modules

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm trying to build a multi sub-modules project using maven 3.3.9 with --fail-at-end. Running one cycle of this phase took so much time (some hours) and in every cycle i solve problems in building some of sub-modules and running maven build again (starting another cycle).
So the question is: Is there any way to force maven not to try building packages which been built successfully in previous cycles?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you really running a build over hours? How many code lines (10 million lines?) ? How many tests? 10 or 50 thousands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a multi module project and you are trying to get a complete, successful build via an iterative process of ...

```
build -> fail -> fix the failure -> rebuild
```

... and each time around that loop you'd like to resume with the module in which the failure occurred rather than building the whole project every time.

The standard approach to this use case is to use `-rf`:

```
-rf, --resume-from
    Resume reactor from specified project
```

For example, if the module named `moduleD` fails then re-run your build as follows:

```
mvn -rf :moduleD install
```

More details [in the docs](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/).

You might also choose not to include the `clean` phase when re-running your build, thereby allowing Maven's incremental compiler to work out what needs to be rebuilt.